# Can I prune a parser's vocabulary in spaCy?

Tags: vocabulary, spacy

The following code uses [spaCy word vectors](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/word-vectors-similarities) to find the 20 most similar words to a given word by first computing cosine similarity for all words in the vocabulary (more than a million), then sorting this list of the most similar words.

```
parser = English()

# access known words from the parser's vocabulary
current_word = parser.vocab[word]

# cosine similarity
cosine = lambda v1, v2: dot(v1, v2) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2))

# gather all known words, take only the lowercased versions
allWords = list({w for w in parser.vocab if w.has_vector and w.orth_.islower() and w.lower_ != word})

# sort by similarity
allWords.sort(key=lambda w: cosine(w.vector, current_word.vector))
allWords.reverse()

print("Top 20 most similar words to %s:") % word
for word in allWords[:20]:   
    print(word.orth_)
```

What I would like to know is whether there is **a way to restrict spaCy's vocabulary only to the words that occur in a given list**, which I hope would hugely reduce the cost of the sort operation.

To be clear, I would like to pass in a list of just a few words, or just the words in a given text, and be able to rapidly look up which of these words are nearest each other in spaCy's vector space.

Any help on this front appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The SpaCy documentation says that:

> The default English model installs vectors for one million vocabulary
>   entries, using the 300-dimensional vectors trained on the Common Crawl
>   corpus using the GloVe algorithm. The GloVe common crawl vectors have
>   become a de facto standard for practical NLP.

So you could just load the [GloVe vectors](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) using Gensim. I'm not sure if you can load them directly, or if you have to use [this script](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/glove2word2vec.html).

If you have loaded the word vectors in Gensim as `model`, you can simply use `word_vectors.similarity('woman', 'man')` to get the similarity between two words. If you have a list of words, you could do something like:

```
def most_similar(word, candidates, model, n=20):
    "Get N most similar words from a list of candidates"
    similarities = [(model.similarity(word,candidate), candidate) 
                    for candidate in candidates]
    most_similar_words = sorted(similarities, reverse=True)[:n]
    only_words = [w for sim,w in most_similar_words]
    return only_words
```

Answer (score 0):

Spacy has a `Vectors` class that has a `most_similar` method. You could then define a wrapper function like so to avoid writing your own implementation:

```
import spacy
import numpy as np

def most_similar(word, model, n=20):
    nlp = spacy.load(model)
    doc = nlp(word)
    vecs = [token.vector for token in doc]
    queries = np.array(vecs)
    keys_arr, best_rows_arr, scores_arr = nlp.vocab.vectors.most_similar(queries, n=n)
    keys = keys_arr[0] # The array of keys is nested in another array from the previous step.
    similar_words_list = [nlp.vocab[key].text for key in keys]
    return similar_words_list
```

And call it like this: `most_similar('apple', 'en_core_web_md', n=20)` This would find the 20 most similar words using cosine similarity of the word "apple" based on the the Spacy model package "en_core_web_md".

This is the result: `['BLACKBERRY', 'APPLE', 'apples', 'PRUNES', 'iPHone', '3g/3gs', 'fruit', 'FIG', 'CREAMSICLE', 'iPad', 'ipad4', 'LONGAN', 'CALVADOS', 'iPOD', 'iPod', 'SORBET', 'PERSICA', 'peach', 'juice', 'JUICE']`